# Does mixing two different dataset influence the accuracy of the YOLO object detection?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolo

I've been training a YOLOV3 model, which detects head and human body on darknet53 backbone. I have two separate datasets: head (Brainwash head dataset) and body (MIT Pedestrian Data). If I trained YOLOv3 on each dataset separately, it could reach a good enough accuracy.

But now, I want to train a model which could detect the two things at the same time. So I simply mixed the two dataset together. But the head dataset only marks the head, and the MIT dataset only marks the body.

My question is: **Does mixing the two different dataset reduce the accuracy of YOLOv3 object detection?** And why?

I don't know if such a mixed dataset will reduce the accuracy which I trained separately before. I'm just new to this field. Thanks for any helping.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer will be: yes, such a mixed dataset will reduce the performance of your model.

The reason is because while your model might learn something from the data where the head of the individuals is annotated, it will penalized when it encounters an image where the body is tagged but the head isn't.

A merge of this kind between the datasets will add a large number of false negatives and the model will have a hard time to converge, most probably it will overfit your data. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives) resource might be helpful for you.